# Is there a way to set the subclass CGPoint in itself?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uilabel

There's a subclass of UILabel called NewLabel, it will shows in lots of UIViewControllers, such as

```
NewLabel *label = [[NewLabel alloc] init];
CGSize size = CGSizeMake(120.0f, 40.0f);
CGPoint point = CGPointMake(self.view.bounds.size.width / 2, self.view.bounds.size.height / 2);
label.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height);
label.center = point;
[self.view addSubview:label];
```

In each UIViewController, I need to put these codes, can I compact the code, and put some in subclass `NewLabel`? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create some static factory method in NewLabel class or in other class, that will have next structure:

```
+ (NewLabel*)addLabelIntoView:(UIView*)view
{
   NewLabel *label = [[NewLabel alloc] init];
   CGSize size = CGSizeMake(120.0f, 40.0f);
   CGPoint point = CGPointMake(view.bounds.size.width / 2, view.bounds.size.height / 2);
   label.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height);
   label.center = point;
   [view addSubview:label];
   return label;
}
```

And add the label just calling this method:

```
<....>
self.label = [NewLabel addLabelIntoView:self.view]
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to do 2 things here:

1) set a constant size for the label.
2) center the label in its superview.

I would approach those 2 things separately.

For the first one (setting the size), it depends on the purpose. (120, 40) feels pretty arbitrary to me. What if the text is longer than 120px in a different language? What if I want to increase the iOS font size in settings and it becomes higher than 40px? What if I make the screen smaller in a split-screen? If you are not sure, maybe using [sizeToFit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622630-sizetofit?language=objc) or auto-layout is a solution. If you are absolutely sure about the size, it might be moved to be an [intrinsic content size](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622600-intrinsiccontentsize?language=objc) of the NewLabel.

For centering a label it is a perfect use case for autolayout. [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29975778/how-to-center-uilabel-horizontally-and-vertically-in-screen-using-auto-layout). This solution could be extracted as an utility method like `centerViewInSuperview`.

Another solution to this would be to actually extract this whole concept of a label located at the center into a separate UIView, which contains that label in the middle. Then in your code you would use that view instead, and just fill it to the entire view controller's view (could also add constraints that attach its borders to the parent borders for cases like resizing on rotation).